Unique isomorphism between dual objects that preserve duality data.
In Tensor Categories, page 48, it is said that the isomorphism $\alpha:X_1^{*} \to X_2^{*}$ they construct, is the only isomorphism between (right) dual objects that preserve the evaluation and coevaluation; What exactly do they mean by this? They say it is easy to show, but I don't know exactly what they mean by preserve.

This is meant in the sense that the obvious diagram commutes, i.e.

That is, $e_2 \circ (\alpha \otimes X) = e_1$ and $(X \otimes \alpha) \circ c_1 = c_2$.
In other words, adopting the univalent point of view, $\alpha$ induces an identification $p : X_1^* = X_2^*$, and we are asking for dependent identifications $e_1 =_p e_2$ and $c_1 =_p c_2$ over $p$ (which should assemble into an identification $(X_1^*, e_1, c_1) = (X_2^*, e_2, c_2)$ as left duals of $X$).

Dear Naim, thanks for the answer, it makes sense. On another note, what is a "univalent point of view"?

As introduced in homotopy type theory. See also structure identity principle and univalent category.
