Exact faithful functor between rigid abelian tensor categories.
Let $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{C}'$ be rigid abelian tensor categories, with identity objects $\mathbf{1},\mathbf{1}'$ respectively. If $\text{End}(\mathbf{1})$ is a field, and $\mathbf{1}'\neq 0$, it is claimed in Tannakian Categories (prop. 1.19) that every exact tensor functor $F:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}'$ is faithful.
The proof given is:

The criterion in $\mathcal{C}$, $X \neq 0 \iff X \otimes X^{\vee} \to \mathbf{1}$ is an epimorphism is respected (my italic) by $F$.

Now, I I think I understand why the criterion holds in $\mathcal{C}$ (see Alex Saads own answer here Epimorphisms and faithful functors in a rigid abelian tensor category). But what exactly do they mean by "$F$ respects the criterion"? Do they mean that $F(X) \neq 0 \iff F(X \otimes X^{\vee}) \to \mathbf{1}'$ holds? If yes, then how does this prove that $F$ is faithful?
My initial thoughts: It seems to hold that $FX = 0 \implies X = 0$ if $F$ is an exact functor between abelian categories. So assume that $FX = 0$, then $F(X \otimes X^{\vee}) \to \mathbf{1}'$ is not an epimorphism. Here, I am stuck; what conclusion can I draw from this? Is there a reason for concluding that in fact $X \otimes X^{\vee} \to \mathbf{1}$ is then not an epimorphism, hence $X = 0$?

The meaning is that $F$ preserves the truth of this condition; that is,

since $F$ is a tensor functor, $F(X \otimes X^{\ast}) \cong F(X) \otimes F(X)^{\ast}$,
furthermore $F$ sends the counit $X \otimes X^{\ast} \to 1$ to the counit $F(X) \otimes F(X)^{\ast} \to F(1)$ of $F(X)$, and
since $F$ is an exact functor, it preserves epimorphisms.

Altogether it follows that if the counit of $X$ is an epimorphism the same is true of $F(X)$, so if $X$ is nonzero, then $F(X)$ is nonzero. Taking the contrapositive, an equivalent claim is that if $F(X) = 0$ then $X = 0$.
Call such a functor between abelian categories weakly faithful. The second half is a general fact about abelian categories: if $F : A \to B$ is an exact functor between abelian categories, then it is faithful iff it is weakly faithful. This is because a map $f : X \to Y$ in an abelian category is zero iff $\text{im}(f) = 0$, and exact functors preserve images (since they preserve kernels and cokernels). So
$$\begin{align*} F(f) = 0 &\Leftrightarrow \text{im}(F(f)) = 0 & \text{by above} \\
 &\Leftrightarrow F(\text{im}(f)) = 0 & \text{by exactness} \\
 &\Leftrightarrow \text{im}(f) = 0 & \text{by weak faithfulness} \\
 &\Leftrightarrow f = 0 & \text{by above}. \end{align*}$$
Here the notation is sort of obscuring what is going on; in the first and last equalities the two things being compared are morphisms, while in the middle the things being compared are objects.

Note that this whole argument is a categorification of the argument that a homomorphism $F : K \to L$ between two fields is injective (namely, if $k \in K$ is nonzero then $k k^{-1} = 1$, so $F(k k^{-1}) = F(k) F(k)^{-1} = 1$, so $F(k)$ is nonzero). This suggests the idea that rigid abelian tensor categories with $\text{End}(1)$ a field are some kind of "categorified fields," with rigidity playing the role of a categorified weakening of invertibility.


Wow, this is great =). Right, so my understanding is that if the counit of $X$ is an epimorphism, then since $F$ respects this, we know that the counit of $F(X)$ is an epimorphism; but then $F(X) \neq 0$ since if $F(X) = 0$ then $F(X) \otimes F(X)^{\vee}$ would be zero, and then we would get a $0$-map, but a $0$-map can not be an epimorphism. As you say, the contrapositive becomes $F(X) = 0 \implies X = 0$. Correct anything I said that is wrong, please.

Just another question; what is the relevance of $f = 0$ here? If $F$ is an exact functor between abelian categories, is it the case that if $F(f) = F(g) \iff F(f-g) = 0$, and then we want to show that this implies that $f-g = 0$?

@Ben: yes, that's right. If $F$ is an additive functor between abelian categories then $F(f) = F(g) \Leftrightarrow F(f) - F(g) = 0 \Leftrightarrow F(f - g) = 0$ (since additivity gives $F(f - g) = F(f) - F(g)$), so an additive functor between abelian categories is faithful iff it satisfies $F(f) = 0 \Rightarrow f = 0$. This equivalence doesn't require exactness.

This has been very helpful, thanks =).

I am puzzled by the fact that you seem to not use the hypothesis that $\text{End}(\mathbf{1})$ is a field, and $\mathbf{1}' \neq 0$, anywhere, atleast not explicitly? Well, it seems more explicit in your edit (AFAICT). But I don't see where we, in particular, use that $\text{End}(\mathbf{1})$ is a field, in your original post.

Right, ok, I think $\mathbf{1}' \neq 0$ is used when we say that $F(f)$ can not be an epimorphism if $FX = 0$, since otherwise we would have that $FX = 0$ then the counit would be the unique map (which is an iso, hence epi, from the zero object to itself). However, I still fail to see where we use that $\text{End}(\mathbf{1})$ is a field. I suppose we want to use that then $\mathbf{1}$ is a simple object (coming from prop. 1.18 in Tannakian Categories).

Oh, wait. Yes, we do use this actually, we used that $\text{End}(\mathbf{1})$ is a field to see that the criterion $X \neq 0 \iff X \otimes X^{\vee} \to \mathbf{1}$ epi, holds in $\mathcal{C}$.

I haven't worked through the details but that sounds right to me. This criterion doesn't hold in $\text{Vect}^2$, for example.

Ops, should be "coming from prop 1.17)..."two comments above.

There is one thing I still don't understand: I recall Naïm Favier telling me that the counit of $F(X \otimes X^{\vee})$ and $F(X) \otimes F(X)^{\vee}$ are related by a formula similar to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4946206/unique-isomorphism-between-dual-objects-that-preserve-duality-data
But I have not seen (as far as I can recall) a proof for why this is. This seems very related to your second bulletpoint in your answer.  Do you know why this holds? I'd be happy for any reference if you can not give a complete proof.
Best.

@Ben123: this is a general property of tensor functors. Tensor functors always preserve dualizable objects (sending duals to duals, units to units, counits to counits); the point is that they preserve tensor products and also preserve the zigzag identities. In other words dualizability is a "purely equational" condition in the language of tensor categories.

It's just like in that question, really: $F(X^)$ and $(FX)^$ are both duals for $FX$, so they are isomorphic and their units/counits are identified over the isomorphism.

Hm, well, I know that Deligne/Milne says that in rigid tensor categories, we have that the eval. morphism for $X^{\vee} \otimes Y$ as internal hom is $X^{\vee} \otimes Y \otimes X \simeq X^{\vee} \otimes X \otimes Y \overset{\text{ev}_{X} \otimes \text{id}}{\to} \mathbf{1} \otimes Y \simeq Y$. This would ofc motivate what you both said, since we are really expressing the evaluation-maps for internal-homs in terms of the evaluation-morphisms for the dual objects, and they are preserved, as you both said. I am still trying to picture some diagram for this. I'll have to think about it more.
